# How can I pass timer information from my main scene to another(Try Again) scene? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a timer in my main scene and I'm trying to pass the time score to another scene. The scene that I'm trying to pass it is Try Again scene, so I mean I want the user to be able to see the score they got in the last game they played.

I watched a lot of youtube videos, explaining how to pass values, but it did not help me.

Player Script:

```
public Text timerText;
private float startTime;

void Start()
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float t = Time.time - startTime;

        string minutes = ((int) t / 60).ToString();
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2 ");

        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
```

Try Again Scene:

[image: Try Again Scene]

Trying to pass the result of Player Script to Try Again Scene.

Comment: use a static variable or if you don't want the game object to be destroyed when switching to another scene use `UnityEngine.Object.DontDestroyOnLoad()`.

Comment: You mean in Player Script?

Comment: in whatever it is that you want to keep. Does Player have the information you need in the second scene? Yes? - then yes, maybe you should keep Player.

Comment: Roberto That is bad practice. @Mahdiyar you should use scriptableObjects for this

Comment: @Stanley Could you please tell me more about it and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scriptable oject**

You should be using a scriptableObject instead of a monobehaviour inheritance.
[image: How to implement a scriptable object]

A scriptableObject lives in the folders and acts like a GameObject. This means that it does not have to be instantiated for it to get and set values.

Imagine having a gameobject/script with all the global information you need that never gets destroyed.

so you could say:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "GlobalVariables", menuName = "ScriptableObject: global variables")]
     public class GlobalVariable: ScriptableObject {
         public int time; 
    }
```

---

```
public class TimeCount : MonoBehaviour {

    public GlobalVariable variableStorage;

        public void Update() {
            variableStorage.time = Time.time;
        }
     }
```

and then you just need to drag the scriptableObject into the variableStorage field in the inspector: image of my game
[image]

for more information take a look at this vide: https://youtu.be/TLVf4ky7I3k

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me, but could you please tell where exactly I suppose to place `public class TimeCount {...}` and `[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "GlobalVariables", menuName = "ScriptableObject: global variables")]`? I'm kind of new, so sorry about that.

Comment: Those should both be in their own scripts.. so one script named TimeCount and one script named GlobalVariable

Comment: After making both those scripts attatch the TimeCount to a gameObject inside the scene.

Then you rightclick inside your scripts folder and create "ScriptableObject: globalVariables" and drag that into the first gameobject with the timecount script on it @Mahdiyar

Comment: The last thing, I did all the things you said, but what I should do to attach all that to my text(Your Score), so that it works? Thanks

Comment: I dont quite understand what youre trying to do. Could you provide more information? preferably an image link

Comment: ScriptableObjects aren't made to store dynamic values, if I understand it correctly he wants to pass the score that the player had when playing to another scene.

Comment: @Roberto That may not have been the reason they were made but that is the best solution i could see to this problem and it should not be a problem to use dynamic variables in the way he desires inside a scriptable object.

Comment: My purpose is to pass the time score that player got from the game to Try Again scene when they lost, so that player is able to see the final time score.

Comment: add my discord and i'll take a look: LIFE#2123 @Mahdiyar

Comment: why is Scriptable Object the best solution?

Comment: because he wants to save a global variable across multiple scenes? or am i genuinely wrong?

Comment: He could use a plain C# class to do that. C# objects are not destroyed between scenes. Or the could use DontDestroyOnLoad if he wants to keep a Unity object. There's no use case for ScriptableObject here.

Comment: @Roberto but you cannot create an object of a c# monobehaviour inherited script.. Using dontdestroyonload function creates a mess in general, if the object is not instantiated correctly he could never go back into that scene without getting another copy of the gameobject that has donotdestroyonload connected to it.

Unity has an entire hour of presentation on why you should use scriptableobjects instead of donotdestroyonload from unite keynote 2017 or 2018.

Comment: Do you have the link? I couldn't find that talk. What I mean with pure C# object is that he doesn't need MonoBehaviour or any Unity class to do that. A pure C# class with a `public static int Score` would resolve his issue. He doesn't want to save the score into a file, your answer is even more wrong because it tells him to create a ScriptableObject file - if you want to use ScriptableObject you can do so by calling ScriptableObject.CreateInstance, you don't need to create any .asset files.

Comment: @Roberto Hmm, havent heard about that solution, that would be great if it worked. here is the link anyway, thanks for the discussion! :) https://youtu.be/6vmRwLYWNRo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200204/discussion-between-roberto-and-stanley).